# How to call a static block of magento extension in .phtml file?

Tags: magento

I have installed an extension for slider on my home page. It has given me a static block code.

```
 Call via block:
 {{block type="responsivebannerslider/index" name="responsivebannerslider_index" template="responsivebannerslider/index.phtml"}}
```

Dont know how call it in .phtml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('responsivebannerslider/index')->setTemplate('responsivebannerslider/index.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can call it from your template by creating a block on the layout directly in the phtml template file:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('responsivebannerslider/index')->setTemplate('responsivebannerslider/index.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Or if the block is listed in the extensions layout XML file, (which would be nested within a reference node), and would look something like:

```
<block type="responsivebannerslider/index" name="responsivebannerslider_index" as="an_alias" template="responsivebannerslider/index.phtml">
    <label>Responsive banner</label>
</block>
```

And you'd call that in your template file like:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('an_alias'); ?>
```